# Best way to access a vector via strings instead of integers

Tags: c++, matlab, vector, differential-equations

Accessing into a vector is usually done via integers, i.e. `v[0]`. But, say I wanted do something morally like `v["string"]`? What's the best way to do this.

For example using a map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main() {

    // make some data
    std::vector<int> data{ 2,4,6,8,10 };

    // can access by integers of course
    for (int i = 0; i != data.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "data[i]: " << data[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // what if I want to access by strings?
    std::vector<std::string> pos{ "pos1", "pos2", "pos3", "pos4", "pos5" };
    std::map<std::string, int> m = { {"pos1", 0}, {"pos2", 1}, {"pos3", 2}, {"pos4", 3}, {"pos5", 4} };

    for (auto p : pos) {
        std::cout << "data[m[p]]: " << data[m[p]] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The reason for this is to improve readability in a considerable amount of equations. Something like `dX[1] = X[1] - X[1]*X[2]` is easy enough to keep track of when there are only a couple of state variables. But, when there are thousands of different states it would be nice to have something like `dX["rabbit"] = X["rabbit"] - X["rabbit"]*X["fox"]` to improve readability. I think any such method will slow a solver down too much, but I'm curious to see what others think. (Bonus points if anyone knows a good way in MATLAB. `containers.Map` stinks.)

Comment: Have you considered using integer constants?

Comment: What's wrong with using `std::map`? Can you please try to elaborate on the problems you have? And please, one question per question, if you have a question relating to a completely different environment and language, then please post it as a separate question.

Comment: `enum Pos : std::size_t { n, i, ii, iii, iv, v, vi, vii, viii, ix, x };`

Comment: `auto& rabbit = X[1]; auto& fox = X[2]; rabbit = rabbit - rabbit * fox;` ???

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `std::unordered_map`?

You can use it as a map, though it will use hashing to access in (if I recall well) log(1) complexity your entry. I provide you the link of the docs:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

On many benchmarks it outperforms `std::map`.

Regarding waht you propose, of course the method shall slow down the solver, but `unordered_map` is an upgrade over `map`.

I hope this helps, and points you somewhere useful.

Regarding MATLAB, in my limited experience `containers.Map` stinks and maybe it is appropriate for humanity to keep it this way ;)